# sitecore if FieldRenderer has no value, don't display it

Tags: field, sitecore

in Sitecore I have a template I have created which have a bunch of FieldRenderers. Basically sometimes the value isn't filled in so I want to hide the div it's within, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: are you using a user control or an xslt?

Comment: Hi Marto, using a user control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways depending on how often you are going to use it.

1. Create a custom templated control ([here is a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx) jump straight to Building a Non-Databound Templated Server Control) called CustomFieldRenderer to which you can pass a display template. In the case the property returns blank you can hide the whole control
2. If it's only for a single page I would create a literal and set the value from the code behind like this

the html will be

```
<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Id="SitecoreField">
<div>{0}</div>
</asp:Literal>
```

the code behind will be like this

```
string value = FieldRenderer.Render(Sitecore.Context.Item, "FieldName");
SitecoreField.Visible = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false;
SitecoreField.Text = string.Format(SitecoreField.Text, value);
```

Comment: Hi Marto, thanks for reply. Having a bit of trouble with getting it to work, think I'm missunderstabnding something! Using the following:

<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Id="Phone"> 
<div class="callbox"> 
<p></p> 
</div> 
</asp:Literal> 

and:

string value = FieldRenderer.Render(Sitecore.Context.Item, "Phone");
Phone.Visible = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false;
Phone.Text = string.Format(Phone.Text, value);

Phone is the name of the fieldrender

Comment: your seem to be missing the placeholder {0}. The literal should be `<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Id="Phone"> <div class="callbox"> <p>{0}</p> </div> </asp:Literal>`

Answer (score 8):

This assumes the context item, but change the item reference as needed in your scenario:

In the **ascx**:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMyField" runat="server">
  <sc:FieldRenderer FieldName="My Field" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

In the **ascx.cs**:

```
pnlMyField.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Context.Item["My Field"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a control specifically for this purpose. Basically the same as Mark's answer, but without the need for code-behind.

```
<e:Enclosure runat="server">
  <div>
    <sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="My Field" />
  </div>
</e:Enclosure>
```

Now, when the FieldRenderer doesn't have any output, the div isn't displayed either.
The code and some more explanation about this can be found on my blog: http://wensveen.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/toggling-boilerplate-html-visibility-in-asp-net/

Sorry for the shameless plug, but I think it might be helpful.

Comment: Can't be sorry if it is shameless ;)  -- Thanks for the link / post though. Great stuff.